# Nested Arrays losing formatting when posted to MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working with Node MongoDB and Express.  I'm receiving a JSON from an API call and trying to pass it along to my DB.  It's making it to the DB but any nested arrays are losing their structure and being turned into a structure such as..

```
    "nutritionEstimates[0][attribute]" : "FAT_KCAL",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][description]" : "",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][value]" : "310",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][unit][id]" : "fea252f8-9888-4365-b005-e2c63ed3a776",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][unit][name]" : "calorie",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][unit][abbreviation]" : "kcal",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][unit][plural]" : "calories",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][unit][pluralAbbreviation]" : "kcal",
    "nutritionEstimates[0][unit][decimal]" : "true",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][attribute]" : "CAFFN",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][description]" : "Caffeine",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][value]" : "0.03",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][unit][id]" : "12485d26-6e69-102c-9a8a-0030485841f8",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][unit][name]" : "gram",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][unit][abbreviation]" : "g",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][unit][plural]" : "grams",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][unit][pluralAbbreviation]" : "grams",
    "nutritionEstimates[1][unit][decimal]" : "true",
```

I don't know specifically whats causing this but I suspect perhaps it's monk trying to format the JSON, and it won't pass the data along at all if I try to pass it as a string.  Some of my code to follow for a reference.  App Id and Key removed.

```
function saveRecipe(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var recipeUrl = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/' + this.value + '?_app_id=&_app_key=';
  var json = $.getJSON(recipeUrl, function (data){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: data,
       url: '/saverecipe',
       dataType: 'JSON'
   });
 });
};
```

And the start of my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/favorite-recipes')

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
```

I appreciate any insight anyone could provide.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bodyParser option "extended".  It was set to false and wouldn't allow complex objects. Removing this option resolved all issues.